# Multiple NAS-IP-Address check attributes in FreeRadius?

Tags: networking, freeradius, freeradius2

is it possible to have an OR statement in freeradius check attributes?

I have say 10 VPN servers that authenticate from freeradius. Most users can access all servers but I have a demo user that can only access 2 of those servers.

I can set this up so that the demo can only access 1 of the servers by putting the following in the radcheck table/users file

```
NAS-IP-Address==xxx.xxx.xxx.1
```

But I need to have and OR statement in there like:

```
NAS-IP-Address==xxx.xxx.xxx.1 OR xxx.xxx.xxx.2
```

Is this possible in freeradius?

Comment: You could have a fallthrough I think..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `=~` operator, and a regex `xxx.xxx.xxx.1|xxx.xxx.xxx.2`

Reference: http://freeradius.1045715.n5.nabble.com/Logical-OR-with-Check-Attributes-td3265998.html

Comment: you sir are a star!

Comment: Nah, just someone with freeradius experience, and a knack with google :)

Comment: @user1167223 remember to mark it as resolved.. :)

Comment: done, couldnt do it before, it insisted I waited 10 mins and I had to go out :)

Answer (score 0):

It's only on freeradius 2.x can work.

On 3.x can't use.

(1) sql: ERROR: Error parsing value: Failed resolving "=xxx.xxx.xxx.1|=xxx.xxx.xxx.2|=xxx.xxx.xxx.3|=xxx.xxx.xxx.4" to IPv4 address: Name or service not known
(1) sql: ERROR: Error parsing user data from database result
(1) sql: ERROR: Error getting check attributes

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Your answer currently does not seem to provide a workable solution to the question and might be more appropriate as a question. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask) And don't forget to take the [site tour](http://serverfault.com/tour).